# Stripe: how to replenish user's credits on renewal date?

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

Basically I have a user subscribe to a plan, and he gets X number of credits. This credits must be replenished when his subscription gets renewed. How can I check if the user's account status from Stripe API and determine if his monthly subscription has been renewed, and if so, allow me to replenish his credit on my data base?

If he fails to renew, it should be that he does not get more credits.

What api features exists in Stripe to let me get the subscription status so that I can replenish a user's credits based on renewal date or cancellation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#retrieve_subscription) it should be as simple as:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve("your_customer_id")
subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve("the_customers_subscription_id")
if subscription["status"] == "active":
    # The customer has an active subscription
```

Comment: but I need to know what day the renewal happens so I can trigger the credit replenishment.

Comment: Then look at `subscription["current_period_end"]` (if the API docs are to be believed) :-)

Comment: so on login, check if subscription is still active, and check if todays date matches current_period_end?

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to subscribe to events and replenish credits every time the customer successfully billed? `invoice.paid ` event might be what you are looking for.